# How to underline the menu items with a custom glyph

Tags: css, menu, center, glyph

I managed to add a custom glyph under the currently selected menu item on my website. But I don't know how to center the glyph... The first one is centered, but when we hover over the other menu items, they have varying lengths and the centering is lost... It is purely css, based on the "a::after" property. Does anyone have a creative idea?

Here is the website: [www.latelierdegaia.ch](http://www.latelierdegaia.ch)
and below is the CSS. Thank you so much in advance!

```
.navigation-top a::after {
width: 60px;
content: " ";
background-image: url('images/menu-glyph-2.png');
background-size: 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
position: absolute;
left: 5%;
bottom: 0px;
height:30px;
opacity: 0;
-o-transition:.3s;
-ms-transition:.3s;
-moz-transition:.3s;
-webkit-transition:.3s;
transition: 0.3s;
-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility:hidden;
-ms-backface-visibility:hidden;
-o-backface-visibility:hidden;
}

.navigation-top li:hover > a::after,
.navigation-top li.focus > a::after, 
.current_page_item > a::after {
opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the rule for the `::after` pseudo element, change `width` to `100%` and `background-size` to `60px auto;`, and add `background-position: center top`.

Comment: Thank you so much Johannes! That solved it perfectly! What would I do without the the stackoverflow community... 
:)